# Android unlock features by in app payment

Tags: android, payment

I have made an app with some features as standard and some features locked (plus features).
All features are shipped with the app, but only the standard ones are visible.

The app basically does this:

- If it finds a standard feature -> the app always shows it.
- If it finds a 'plus' feature -> the app checks a persistence file to see if the 'isPlus' flag is true or false. If true, the app shows the feature, if false, the app doesn't show it.

When the app is installed, the 'isPlus' flag is false.
I want to put a 'Pay' button into the app. When this is clicked, a pay screen should appear and the user does the payment. If they make the payment, the 'isPlus' flag should get set to true. Then the app will refresh what it is showing and so the 'plus' features will also be shown.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far, and what your problem is with that code? I assume you done some research yourself. If not this is a good start: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Comment: "a pay screen should appear" - How far are you with implementing just that part? Can you show that code?

Comment: Is there not a built in google api for paying for in game content. I think it persists with the user account, so that once they buy it, they have it forever. And you just check against the API if they have the module? [Check this out](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) Supports the payment pages too.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I haven't implemented any part of the payment system yet. Just researching what will be needed. I will now have a look at the links you provided. Cheers, Jim